# No puedo acceder a las propiedades de un Objeto da "UNDEFINED" como resultado el console.log(objeto.propiedad)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose

Al realizar una consulta utilizando **Express** y **Mongoose**, y utilizando `console.log` para revisar el resultado del siguiente código:

```
const consults = await Consult.find({ user: req.user.id }).populate('patient', 'patient_name patient_phone');

    console.log(typeof(consults));
    console.log(consults);
    console.log(consults._id);
    console.log(consults.c_motive);
    console.log(consults.c_amount);
    console.log(consults.c_cDate);
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado de los console.log()

```
console.log(typeof(consults));
```

Resultado//

```
object
```

console.log(consults); 
Resultado//

```
[ { _id: 5d9f483c1cb2710408aeaf20,
    c_note:
     'Se presento con un dolor de estomago recurrente, y diarrea.',
    c_prescription: 'Tinidazol',
    c_motive: 'Dolor de estomago recurrente',
    c_amount: 200,
    c_recurrent: 'New',
    c_cDate: 2019-10-10T15:03:24.144Z,
    user: 5d9574bcc31c0e10c83fcb3b,
    patient:
     { _id: 5d9f47811cb2710408aeaf1f,
       patient_name: 'Miguel Marroquin',
       patient_phone: '40009374' },
    c_status: 'PAID',
    __v: 0 } ]

console.log(consults._id);
```

Resultado//

```
undefined

console.log(consults.c_motive);
```

Resultado//

```
undefined

console.log(consults.c_amount);
```

Resultado//

```
undefined

console.log(consults.c_cDate); 

introducir el código aquí
```

Resultado//

```
 undefined
```

Como logro acceder a las propiedades del objeto para trabajar con ellas?

Comment: `consults` es un array al parecer, entonces deberías hacer algo como `consults[0]._id`

Comment: Funciono! si ascribes una respuesta la doy como correcta.

Comment: Hola Miguel, ya fue contestada la pregunta pero te recomiendo que manejes las interfaces para un fácil acceso a esas propiedades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`consults` te esta devolviendo un `vector` que por dentro tiene 2 objetos donde 1 esta dentro de otro

- El primer valor por ejemplo empieza por la clave `_id`
- El objeto empieza por la clave `patient` **(este es el otro objeto)**

Entonces para poder acceder a los valores necesitas:

- Indicar el índice que identifique a que objeto haces referencia
- La clave del objeto e iterar este mismo

Por ejemplo para a alguno de los valores antes del objeto puedes recuperar los valores asi:

```
console.log(datos[0].c_note)
```

Dando esto como resultado:

> "Se presento con un dolor de estomago recurrente, y diarrea."

Mientras que para el objeto que tiene una clave al inicio debes hacer esto:

```
for(dato of datos){
  console.log(dato.patient._id)
}
```

Iterar con un `for of` que pèrmite recorrer los valores de un objeto, al final solo indicamos la clave que deseamos recuperar, que sería la clave principal del segundo objeto y la clave interna que deseas imprimir

Comment: @Emeeus yo espero tu respuesta, estoy seguro dejará totalmente en claro el asunto planteado en la pregunta Saludos :)

Comment: muchas gracias, pero creo que tu respuesta es mas que clara.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta [Aprendiz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/299911/28035), soluciona tu problema, el "error" es mas simple, estas ejecutando una consulta que te puede devolver uno o mas registros, lo ideal es que uses [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) asi tu consulta/codigo seria optimo:

```
const consults = await Consult.findOne({ user: req.user.id }) 
                              .populate('patient', 'patient_name patient_phone');

console.log(typeof(consults));
...
...
...
```

Comment: El tema es que necesito obtener todos los resultados no unicamente uno.

Answer (score 1):

Aprendiz ya contesto pero me gustaría agregar algo más.

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera.

Lo encuentro de una manera más facil, barrer el arreglo que regresa con un forEach y acceder de una vez a cualquiera de las propiedades que necesites.

**Ojo si hay otro array dentro de este mismo, de igual maneras podrías apuntar a esa propiedad y recorrerlo con otro forEach.**

```js
const consults = [
  {
    _id: "5d9f483c1cb2710408aeaf20",
    c_note: "Se presento con un dolor de estomago recurrente, y diarrea.",
    c_prescription: "Tinidazol",
    c_motive: "Dolor de estomago recurrente",
    c_amount: 200,
    c_recurrent: "New",
    c_cDate: 2019 - 10 - 19,
    user: "5d9574bcc31c0e10c83fcb3b",
    patient: {
      _id: "5d9f47811cb2710408aeaf1f",
      patient_name: "Miguel Marroquin",
      patient_phone: "40009374"
    },
    c_status: "PAID",
    __v: 0
  }
];

console.log(consults);

consults.forEach( elemento => {


    // El objeto en bruto
    console.log(elemento);

    console.log(elemento._id);
    console.log(elemento.c_amount);
    console.log(elemento.c_cDate);
    console.log(elemento.c_motive);
    console.log(elemento.c_note);
    console.log(elemento.c_prescription);
    console.log(elemento.c_recurrent);
    console.log(elemento.c_status);

    // Accediendo a paciente.
    console.log(elemento.patient._id);
    console.log(elemento.patient.patient_name);
    console.log(elemento.patient.patient_phone);

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="prueba.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```